# when payment is done, why payum is deleting security token?

Tags: payum

when payment is done, why payum is deleting security token ?

I am asking this question just for understanding the way of working in payum.

Thank you.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Wouldn't it be more secure to require a new one?

Comment: But when payment could be failing at that time. it wouldn't be deleted from the database.

Answer (score 3):

tokens were introduced to solve several problems:

- hide sensitive details like payment id or invoice id (ones from database). So user cannot guess it or increment it.
- make the url unique and hard to predict.
- make url life as short as possible. User did the payment and clicked back button. Since the token was deleted server response will be 404. Nothing broken.
- With a token one can easily add expiration logic. If token expired new has to be generated and so on.
- If tokens were compromised you just have to delete them and generate new ones. Give them to users to finish purchase. Order id and payment Id are safe.
- notification is also protected by tokens (where it is possible, not all gateways support it). It is much harder to hack notifications.

maybe something else. I will update the answer while I get it.